# Visual Studio auto hide windows with click instead of hover?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2005 and 2010, is there a way I can get the solution explorer, properties window, etc, to auto hide on click instead of mouse hover? So it would work like this: the Solution explorer is on the right hand side of the window, hidden. You click on it and it brings up with Solution Explorer. Clicking on the Solution Explorer button again would hide the window.